# How can I remove weather icon of uninstalled application from application lens in Dash?

Tags: icons, software-uninstall

I installed Weather and its icon was in launcher as well in application lens in dash. When I unistalled Weather(it not "my weather indicator"), its icon vanished from the launcher  but the icon is still present in application lens in Dash. Is there a way to get rid of it?

Comment: Did you log out/in afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

Look for the corresponding `.desktop` files in `~/.local/share/applications` and in `/usr/share/applications` and remove them.